# curl: No Route to Host port 443?

Tags: docker, curl

I am attempting to install Docker on a raspberry pi 3 cluster using the following instructions:

https://howchoo.com/g/njy4zdm3mwy/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-cluster-with-docker-swarm

On the manager node (0),  wlan0 is configured to connect over the local LAN, and I can get out to the interwebs.

eth0 has a static IP on a small private network for the Pis.

This is raspbian jessie (w/ gui) and has been updated.

When I attempt to launch:

```
for host in node0 node1 node2; do ssh admin@$host curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh; done
```

I get a "No route to host 443" error.  Please advise, have I misconfigured my iptables ruleset or interfaces?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  7 22:38:55 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [1457:118220]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1299:171452]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.1.71 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -s 10.24.28.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Dec  7 22:38:55 2017

/etc/network/interfaces  contains:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.24.28.100
netmask 255.0.0.0
gateway 10.24.28.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this command,
it doesn't run the Docker installer script on `$host`.
It runs it on your current host:

```
ssh admin@$host curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

To execute the script on the remote host, you need to write like this:

```
ssh admin@$host 'curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh'
```

That is, make the pipe `|` part of the remote command.
Otherwise the `| sh` will be executed locally,
using the output of the remote command.